# How to validate files with Yii2 getInstancesByName uploaded from API?

Tags: api, validation, yii2, image-uploading

I'm working on a mobile app, the Yii2 is used as backend API, the problem that I can not validate the uploaded files, any idea how I can do it?

```
    public static function uploadPicture ($vid) {
  $model = new Pictures ();
  $model->load(\Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams(), '');
  $model->vid_image = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstancesByName('vid_image');
  $imageDir = Yii::$app->params[ 'uploadDir' ];


  //if ( $model->validate() AND !empty($model->vid_image) ) { //does not work
  if ( !empty($model->vid_image) ) {
    foreach ( $model->vid_image as $images => $image) {
      $model->name = "t_" . time() . "_i_" . uniqid() . '.' . $image->extension;
      $model->vid = $vid;


      echo $image->hasError;//return empty
      //Yii::$app->end();
      //if ( $model->save() and $model->validate() ) { // does not work
      if(1==1 and $model->validate()){ // $model->validate() always empty!!!
        $image->saveAs($imageDir . '/' . $model->name);
        Yii::$app->getResponse()->setStatusCode(201);
        $id = implode(',', array_values($model->getPrimaryKey(true)));
        Yii::info("[pic.21] image: " . $model->name . " uploaded to: " . $imageDir, __METHOD__);
      } elseif ( $model->hasErrors() ) {
        $response = \Yii::$app->getResponse();
        $response->setStatusCode(500);
        throw new ServerErrorHttpException('Failed to create the object for unknown reason. [APIx001]');
      }
    }
  }
  return $model;
}
```

The files are uploaded without validation.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you read this: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-file-upload ? You must add some validation rules to your model.

Comment: There is, I added the following in the rules, and its working if I use `getInstanceByName` for 1 image file:
        [
     [
      'vid_image'
     ],
     'image',
     'extensions'  => 'png, jpg,jpeg',
     'skipOnEmpty' => true,
     'skipOnError' => false,
     'message' => 'Only jpg and png format is allowed.'
    ],

Comment: try to use my extension for upload the images. P.S. is not validating the files but your code will be clean https://github.com/gomonkey/yii2-easy-uploader